# Как сделать с помощью одного цикла все случаи для a<10?

Tags: javascript

Интерактивная таблица умножения. Как оптимизировать данный код (сократить число строк)?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Таблица умножения 2</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

  </head>
  <body>
 <script> 
 alert ('Интерактивная таблица умножения. Добро пожаловать!');
 var a;
 a = prompt ('Введите наименьший множитель:');

 if (a == 1)  {
 var i = 1;
while (i < 10) {   
  alert("1*" + i + "=" + (1*i));
  i++;            
}
}


if (a == 2)  {
 var i = 2;
while (i < 10) {   
  alert("2*" + i + "=" + (2*i));
  i++;           
}
}



if (a == 3)  {
 var i = 3;
while (i < 10) {   
  alert("3*" + i + "=" + (3*i));
  i++;            
}
}



if (a == 4)  {
 var i = 4;
while (i < 10) {   
  alert("4*" + i + "=" + (4*i));
  i++;           
}
}



if (a == 5)  {
 var i = 5;
while (i < 10) {  
  alert("5*" + i + "=" + (5*i));
  i++;           
}
}


if (a == 6)  {
 var i = 6;
while (i < 10) {   
  alert("6*" + i + "=" + (6*i));
  i++;            
}
}


if (a == 7)  {
 var i = 7;
while (i < 10) {   
  alert("7*" + i + "=" + (7*i));
  i++;            
}
}


if (a == 8)  {
 var i = 8;
while (i < 10) {   
  alert("8*" + i + "=" + (8*i));
  i++;           
}
}

if (a == 9)  {
 var i = 9;
while (i < 10) {  
  alert("9*" + i + "=" + (9*i));
  i++;           
}
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
alert ('Интерактивная таблица умножения. Добро пожаловать!');
var a = +prompt ('Введите наименьший множитель:');

if (a >= 1)  {
  var i = a;
  while (i < 10) {   
    console.log(a + "*" + i + "=" + (a * i));
    i++;            
  }
}
```

Comment: Еще короче: ```if (a >= 1) for (var i = a; i < 10; i++) console.log(`${a} * ${i} = ` + (a * i));```